# YouTube - This video is currently unavailable error message

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm using the latest Android SDK to embed videos in my app, most of them do show but some are showing an error message saying "This video is currently unavailable"

This video is one example and it plays fine on a web browser.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPqgjz6WBPw
```

Anh help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a problem on YouTube's side. It is unlikely that you can can do something about it.

Comment: It seems to work on other platforms such as iOS. I was told that on iOS adding the following attributes this issue was resolved but the Android SDK does not allow to add this in any way: @"origin", @"widget_referrer", @"playsinline"